# Is it possible to use the Javascript Array.prototype.filter() function with an array of other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a Javascript code, I am using an array that contains other arrays.  The array is actually four layers deep (There is an array with arrays of arrays of variables) and I need to remove some strings of a specific value from this array. I had seen the Array.prototype.filter() function and thought it would be useful, but I think it did not work because the strings were within other arrays. I cannot specifically address each sub-array though, for several reasons. Any suggestions for how to make it work or any alternatives would be welcome.

This is an example of a possible array created in my code:

```
[
   [
      [
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            t
         ]
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            t
         ]
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            0.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            1.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            t
         ]
      ],
      [
         [
            t
         ]
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         [
            t
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

I need to remove all of the "t" strings. This array is a bit smaller than it would normally be, and it will be a different size on each execution of the code. If it is unclear what I am asking, or if you thin it would be helpful, I can post the code, but it is a bit big so I don't want to clog up the page.

Comment: `t` is not a string in your code

Comment: What makes you say that? Just to clarify, that array is not part of the code, but the value of the array generated during a test run of the code in question. The lack of quotation marks in the value does not mean that there is a lack of them in the code.  If you have a different reason for saying this, please elaborate, I am always welcome to constructive criticism, but I would like to know why I am wrong when I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> The array is actually four layers deep

You can use object destructuring to get the value of the fourth nested array

```
let res = arr.filter(([[[inner]]]) => typeof inner !== "string");
```

Comment: Oh, wow ... I would never have thought of that one!  But it requires a recent version of the language.

Comment: You could also `.map(x => x.map(y => y.map( z => z.filter(t => t.isString())))`  (or something similar)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it appears either I do not understand correctly, or my development environment has an incompatibility, as it shows a syntax error. could you maybe explain what this piece of code does?

Comment: @AnthonyBaldini Destructuring assignment allows getting an object value by property of a nested element of an array. For example `let arr = [[[[1]]]];
let [[[[n]]]] = arr; console.log(n) // 1`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: what does the greater than or equal statement do in your example?

Comment: @AnthonyBaldini Are you referring to the arrow function syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions ?